# Video tutoarial app IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app that helps users to purchase some tutorial videos. Our plan is to integrate payment through a `UIWebView`. User can do the payment to fill up the form in webview. Once they do the payment, we just track the payment through webservice and they can view the video through the app.

My question is Apple approve this app? because there is no in-app purchase.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with Apple's review policies, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will reject you. Check section `11.2` in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies)

> **11.2** Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected